# What is the best method to sort a dynamic array of c-strings in a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, sorting, computer-science

In my current programming class I've been tasked with creating a program that takes user input course (Consisting of course name, course grade, course units variables) and storing them in a dynamically generated array with a maximum size of 10.

Due to my unfamiliarity with object oriented programming and classes however I'm finding anything beyond the pure creation of the classes to be very difficult. I've figured out a way to create the entries, as well as how to edit them after they've been created using friend functions (I think that's the name?) stored in my programs header file.

However now that I've needed to perform a sort on the data (by the name variable of every entry) as well as to then search it I'm finding it very difficult to proceed. I understand how to make functions that can do both of these things (As I have done it for my previous class), but doing it with classes being involved is proving challenging.

My header file:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>


class Course
{
private:
    char name[10] = ""; //name of course
    char grade; //grade in course
    int units; //units in course

public:
    Course()
    {
        name;
        grade;
        units;
    }

    void read() //Initializes course and collects information from user
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter course name: ";
        std::cin.getline(name, 10, '\n');
        std::cout << "\nEnter number of units: ";
        std::cin >> units;
        std::cout << "\nEnter grade received: ";
        std::cin >> grade;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    void display() const //Displays course to user
    {
        std::cout << name << ' ' << units << ' ' << grade << std::endl;
    }

    ~Course() //Destructor frees allocated dynamic memory
    {
        std::cout << "\nDeleting any dynamically created object";
    }
};

#endif // COURSE_H
```

My main source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "courses.h"

int menu();
void add(Course* co_ptr[], int& size);
void edit(Course* co_ptr[], int size);
void swap_ptrs(Course*& pt1, Course*& pt2);

int main()
{
    Course* courses[10] = {};
    int selection;

    int size = 0;
    do
    {
        selection = menu();

        if (selection == 1)
        {
            if (size < 10)
                add(courses, size);
            else
                std::cout << "\nUnable to add more classes.";
        }
        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            edit(courses, size);
        }
        else if (selection == 3)
        {

        }
        else if (selection == 4)
        {

        }
        else if (selection == 5)
        {

        }
        else if (selection == 6)
        {

        }
        else if (selection == 7)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\nInvalid selection.";
        }
    } while (selection != 7);

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to exit.";
    (void)_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My functions source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "courses.h"

int menu()
{
    int selection;

    std::cout << "\nSelect one of the following actions: " << std::endl
        << "1. Add new course" << std::endl
        << "2. Edit an existing course" << std::endl
        << "3. Display a course" << std::endl
        << "4. List all courses" << std::endl
        << "5. Display GPA" << std::endl
        << "6. Delete all courses" << std::endl
        << "7. Quit";
    std::cout << "\nEnter selection number: ";
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return selection;
}

void add(Course* co_ptr[], int& size)
{
    co_ptr[size] = new Course;
    co_ptr[size]->read();
    size++;
}

void edit(Course* co_ptr[], int size)
{
    int selection;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << i << ". ";
        co_ptr[i]->display();
    }

    std::cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::cin.ignore();

    co_ptr[selection]->read();
}
```

My last attempt at making a sort function (I tried to create it within the header as whenever I ported in my old sorting code as a normal function it couldn't access the data it needed on account of those variables being "private")

```
void Course::sort_name(Course* co_ptr[], int size) //has to be apart of the class (Course::) to have access to the name data
{
    bool swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(co_ptr[i]->name, co_ptr[i + 1]->name) > 0) //We're now comparing and swapping pointers
            {
                swap_ptrs(co_ptr[i], co_ptr[i + 1]);
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Lastly my swap_ptrs function which was also in the function source file:

```
void swap_ptrs(Course*& pt1, Course*& pt2) //Passes the pointers by reference
{
    Course* tmp = pt1;
    pt1 = pt2;
    pt2 = tmp;
}
```

I'm sorry for such a long post but this project has been a real struggle and I'm feeling like I'm not making any headway.

Comment: Just a note: If you have any book teaching the use of `<conio.h>`, that book is probably seriously outdated and not suitable for learning C++. The same applies to a course or book that uses raw `char` arrays for strings.

Comment: Your title is a bit mis-leading. Actually, you want to sort an arrays of pointers while comparing C strings,don't you?

Comment: Correct, I want to sort the array of pointers that point at the c-strings, my mistake on the wording!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a char array. Use string instead

```
char name[10]; //bad form
```

instead use

```
std::string name;
```

coming to your original query if you create a `vector of Course` such as

```
std::vector<Course> mycourselist;
```

then all you need to do is

```
std::sort(mycourselist.begin(),mycourselist.end(), mysortfunc);
```

so you need to write out your own comparison function to do what you want.

so you could do

```
   bool mysortfunc(Course c1, Course c2)
   {
    return c1.name<c2.name;
   }
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: One can use std::sort even on arrays :)

Comment: My answer doesn't say "only std::vector".

Comment: In this particular exercise the OP is statically setting the array size to 10 and so maybe an array makes sense. However for larger sizes where static sizes are not a given vectors will make sense. Barring the minor performance hit, vectors are superior to arrays whatever be the size when it comes to resizing and memory management.

Comment: Agreed. If the size is known at compile time- std::array, else std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a container like std::list or std::vector to store your Course-Objects instead of an array and the use  [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a comparison-method of your choosing. That would probably be the easiest. If you have to stick to arrays as container, you could also use sort like this:

```
std::sort(array, array + array_size,[](Course* a, Course* b) {
        return strcmp(a->name, b->name) < 0;   
    });
```

But that is more like C than C++
...

Answer (score 1):

For sorting, [std::sort()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can be used.

Of course, there is something else necessary – a less predicate which provides the intended order – the `Course*`s sorted by `name` members.

Such a predicate could be:

```
auto lessCourse
    = [](const Course *pCourse1, const Course *pCourse2)
    {
      return strcmp(pCourse1->getName(), pCourse2->getName()) < 0;
    };
```

which is lambda (and could be provided as third argument to `std::sort()` directly).

(A function with same signature would do as well.)

A small demo for illustration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

class Course {
  private:
    char name[10] = ""; //name of course
    char grade; //grade in course
    int units; //units in course

  public:
    explicit Course(const char *name = "", char grade = ' ', int units = 0):
      grade(grade), units(units)
    {
      strncpy(this->name, name, 9);
      this->name[9] = '\0';
    }

    ~Course() = default;
    Course(const Course&) = delete;
    Course& operator=(const Course&) = delete;

    const char* getName() const { return name; }
};

void add(
  Course *pCourses[], unsigned &n,
  const char *name = "", char grade = ' ', int units = 0)
{
  pCourses[n++] = new Course(name, grade, units);
}

int main()
{
  Course *pCourses[10];
  unsigned nCourses = 0;
  // make sample
  add(pCourses, nCourses, "Peter");
  add(pCourses, nCourses, "Carla");
  add(pCourses, nCourses, "Anna");
  add(pCourses, nCourses, "Dieter");
  add(pCourses, nCourses, "Berta");
  // sort sample
  // make a less predicate to compare Course instances by name
  auto lessCourse
    = [](const Course *pCourse1, const Course *pCourse2)
    {
      return strcmp(pCourse1->getName(), pCourse2->getName()) < 0;
    };
  // use std::sort() with that less predicate
  std::sort(pCourses, pCourses + nCourses, lessCourse);
  // output
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nCourses; ++i) {
    const Course *pCourse = pCourses[i];
    std::cout
      << pCourse->getName() << ", "
      << pCourse->getName() << ", oh "
      << pCourse->getName() << ".\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Anna, Anna, oh Anna.
Berta, Berta, oh Berta.
Carla, Carla, oh Carla.
Dieter, Dieter, oh Dieter.
Peter, Peter, oh Peter.
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e405374381f33d12)

Trivia:

Concerning the unusual output format, I used:

[**Trio - Anna - Lassmichrein Lassmichraus**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U639s8fDbMk)